be in somewhere where or be somewhere where


He wanted to be somewhere where he could play every day.




He wanted to be in somewhere where he could play every day.


Which sentence is correct?
As for me, 2 is grammatical because 'wh-clause: relative adjectival clause(here 'where' is relative adverb) should modify the noun antecedent.
"relative adverb 'where'" can be used after adverb? (like in 1)


The troops have been sent to somewhere in France. (from my dictionary)



We looked for somewhere to park the car. (https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/62d66c14747f43de8d3936564810a82a)


I know somewhere nice where we can eat. (https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/62d66c14747f43de8d3936564810a82a)


in search of somewhere to live (https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/62d66c14747f43de8d3936564810a82a)

NOUN somewhere- an unspecified or undetermined place
Edit note:
I now know somewhere is used without preposition and as yet, My 2 is ungrammatical or unidiomatic?

The in is unnecessary, so I suggest you ditch it (you're erroneously conflating the syntactic affordances of somewhere with a place). Plus repeating where after somewhere is clumsy, so ditch that too.

@FumbleFingers I respect your opinion. However, It's hard for me to understand why my grammar view is not applied here.

Languages change over time. See this chart showing how that second where was far more common a few generations ago. But as regards the unwanted in, it's the same as I like to go [to] somewhere [that's] warm for my holidays - the prepositions are unnecessary / unwanted before somewhere (but they're required before a place)..

I think the 'somewhere' is interesting because it's used without preposition even when it is a pronoun: We need to find somewhere to live. (compared a place to live in), I know somewhere we can go.(without to) cf. The troops have been sent to somewhere in France.

Come up and see me at sometime.   Nope.  It's not a nominal form there.  You will have to figiure it out by somehow. Not a pro-form.

I would call them temporal, locative, and manner  thingies and they are not valid objects for prepositions.

TimR, NOUN somewhere- an unspecified or undetermined place

@TimR - If Ms West had said that to me, I might not have been inclined to quibble over a point of grammar. If, that is, I had been born in 1892 approximately.

@FumbleFingers - Plus repeating where after somewhere is clumsy, so ditch that too.  Alas, native speakers, even quite well-educated ones who have been edited by the New Yorker do some very clumsy things. I think it's often to do with showing a certain informality to avoid giving an impression of stiffness.

@gomadeng  That they can be used as pro-forms doesn't mean that  is how they are always used.

I made this comment in another question, but there's nothing wrong with "somewhere where".  Native speakers say it all the time:  I want to eat somewhere (where) they serve seafood.

@TimR My 2 sentence is unidiomatic? And, what about "I want to eat in somewhere they serve seafood."?

@Gomadeng  You sentence #2 is outright ungrammatical, as is "eat in somewhere".

@TimR What about "I am lookinng for somewhere to live in."?

@gomadeng   I can imagine a clumsy native speaker saying it, so let's call it marginal.  somewhere, inasmuch as it refers to an indeterminate place, does not have extension in three-dimensional space or actual location, and so prepositions that entail those meanings are not grammatical. But prepositions that are abstract will work, as one of the example sentences showed: "Who wants to watch a film about somewhere so desolate?"

OP asked, "Which Sentence is Correct?"


He wanted to be somewhere where he could play every day.
He wanted to be in somewhere where he could play every day.


Answer: Both sentences are correct. Sentence 2 is not incorrect or ungrammatical. Similar usages can be found in reputable sources.
Example:


"Sometimes you are in somewhere where you are in danger and it would be good to know what information everyone else has about the situation," said David Tribble, a senior software engineer Grumman.
The New York Times


In both Sentence 2 and the example above, "somewhere" acts as a locative noun, meaning an unspecified place. Like any noun, it can be the object of a preposition such as "in."
The relative adverb "where" introduces a relative clause that modifies "somewhere."
However, the preposition "in" is often unnecessary before "somewhere" and can be omitted for conciseness. That’s why Sentence 1 may sound more natural in everyday usage.
Example of necessary "in":


"Money aside, I always thought about how much more fun it would be to win here rather than jump in somewhere where they already had the pieces," he said.
The New York Times


In this example, "in" is required because the verb "jump in" demands it.
